# How to add quotes " " to every element in non numeric column of a dataframe saved as CSV

Tags: python, pandas

I have DataFrame

```
id,type,value
1,8,value1
2,2,value2
3,7,value3
4,3,value4
5,10,value5
6,3,value16
```

I want to add to the value `id` and `value` of the CSV file to be allocated quotes

```
"1",8,"value1"
"2",2,"value2"
```

What better way to do it

Comment: Maybe show us what you have attempted and what went wrong with your attempts?

Comment: You may want to reconsider choosing @Boud's answer.  That answer applies canonical techniques aimed at writing csv files.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Convert you id column as a string column. Then use the appropriate arguments in function `to_csv`:

```
import csv
df.id = df.id.astype(str)
df.to_csv('test.txt', index=False, quotechar='"',
                      header=None, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
```

`csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC` will apply quotes to all columns that are obviously non numeric like int or float.

Comment: Yes. Side note is: any csv formatting related issue is fixable through to_csv parameters as per my experience, or you're trying to do something off-boundaries and it's not really a csv per se. I recommend always digging into to_csv docstring - I must recognize it's a little obfuscated though

Comment: `df.assign(id=df.id.astype(str), value=df.value.astype(str)).to_csv(
    index=False, quotechar='"',
    header=None, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)`  Prints to screen and proves the point.  I'll dig into it.

Comment: @Boud 
I have and other types, and they are all recorded with " "

Comment: ID           13068 non-null object
Name                  13068 non-null object
ValidFrom       13068 non-null datetime64[ns]
Status           13068 non-null object
Deactivation             0 non-null float64 @Boud

Comment: So deactivation should get no quotes *if you haven't added them manually in the dataframe*, all other coulmns will be quoted as they are not numeric (*object* type). If some of them are supposed to be numeric, convert them in the dataframe before saving (this is the inverse operation of what I wrote in my answer for `id` column. Do astype(int) for instance with a column that contains integers

Comment: @Boud I can not convert my values as a datetime, null and Long in numerical

Answer (score 16):

converting to strings and using `+`

```
df.update('"' + df[['id', 'value']].astype(str) + '"')
print(df)
```

using `applymap`

```
df.update(df[['id', 'value']].applymap('"{}"'.format))
print(df)
```

---

Both yield

```
    id  type      value
0  "1"     8   "value1"
1  "2"     2   "value2"
2  "3"     7   "value3"
3  "4"     3   "value4"
4  "5"    10   "value5"
5  "6"     3  "value16"
```

Comment: Whats the difference between `df.update` vs `df = df.applymap()`? `df.update` won't create a new df?

Comment: @MYGz yes, and I like the syntax better... sometimes

Comment: why when I write Date frame in file, then appears three quotes @piRSquared

Comment: @Ekaterina because here you are doing manual work to put quotes *inside* the dataframe's data, which leads to 1. breaking the contents of your dataframe/take it away from its essence 2. doesn't prevent to_csv function to still behave with its behavior that will be to put quotes around char data. You shouldn't alter your dataframe for presentation reasons as long as the presentation function does it for you.

Comment: @ piRSquared when writing to a file to manually change the quotes were not, the manual change still turns """  (((

Comment: @Ekaterina I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: when I use a second your function and output the data frame, the columns that I wanted to change get " ", I write to a file, then one of the first name of columns in a file have " " the rest of the modified "" "", although they originally had the same types @piRSquared

Comment: That is strange.  I'll play around with it.