# Parse a .txt file with ""

Tags: python, parsing

I have a text file of the following form

```
"0ec62f05-3e87-4143-b417-1571d8634d07","""906823B1-F2D8-4C35-93FB-4C39CB01A8A8""","""Promo_1""",2015-08-27,2015-09-02,700302,,,,12.3.1.1,"""11802,11925,11368""",2017-27-01,"""""""
........
```

how to remove unnecessary "", 
that need to be single

Comment: What's the approximate size of your text file? And are there always either 3 quotes or 1, never 2 or 4 or 5 adjacent quotes?

Comment: Use a regular expression for groups of 2 or more successive double quotes

Comment: @ Jacques de Hooge approximate - 17000 similar  rows

Comment: what have you tried so far? do you have a function or script that's giving you an error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41960346/how-to-add-quotes-to-every-element-in-non-numeric-column-of-a-dataframe-save
@Aaron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a really primitive solution after reading, but it is simply, easy to understand.

```
while(text.count('""')):
    text = text.replace('""', '"')
```

Answer (score 4):

The line seems to be compliant with quoted `csv` format.

For your line, I get this:

```
l = ['''"0ec62f05-3e87-4143-b417-1571d8634d07","""906823B1-F2D8-4C35-93FB-4C39CB01A8A8""","""Promo_1""",2015-08-27,2015-09-02,700302,,,,12.3.1.1,"""11802,11925,11368""",2017-27-01,"""""""''']

import csv

cr = csv.reader(l)
for row in cr:
    print(row)
```

each `row` is a list like this:

```
['0ec62f05-3e87-4143-b417-1571d8634d07', '"906823B1-F2D8-4C35-93FB-4C39CB01A8A8"', '"Promo_1"', '2015-08-27', '2015-09-02', '700302', '', '', '', '12.3.1.1', '"11802,11925,11368"', '2017-27-01', '"""']
```

now for a regular file:

```
import csv

with open("file.csv") as f:    
  cr = csv.reader(f)
  for row in cr:
      print(row)
```

to remove the unnecessary quotes, just replace `row` by `[x.strip('"') for x in row]`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you use string.replace with the double quotes inside the single quote, they will get replaced

```
 oldstring = '"""906823B1-F2D8-4C35-93FB-4C39CB01A8A8"""'
 newstring = oldstring.replace('"""', '"')
```

newstring will appear as `"906823B1-F2D8-4C35-93FB-4C39CB01A8A8"`

Answer (score 1):

I'd split the line by the commas (following the CSV convention), strip all speech marks "" - then go round in a loop, adding the speech marks back to each element of the CSV file.  Something like this...

```
string strippedLine = line.Replace("\"", "");
string[] row = strippedLine.Split(',');

string formattedRow = string.Empty;
string comma = string.Empty;

for (int i = 0; i <= row.Length; i++)
{
    formattedRow += comma + "\"" + strippedLine + "\"";   // <-- Rebuild the line here
    comma = ",";
}
```

So at the end of it, formattedRow will be how you want that line to be.